# How to set variable value at compile time from an expression?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

I am trying to assign sizeof values of some data type to variables at compile time.

I tried following code :

```
constexpr int foo_implementation () {
        return sizeof(int);
}
#define foo std::integral_constant<int, foo_implementation()>::value
int main() {
    int size;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
        size = foo;
        std::cout<<size<<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When i dump the output of preprocessor, it just replace foo with complete statement, which is expected.

My question is will compiler hardcode size to 4 (assuming size of int is 4) or will it call sizeof operator again and again.

If not, how can i fix the value of size at compile time at size of int is know at compile time, to save extra instructions execution at runtime?

Comment: `sizeof(int)` is never actually "called", so you might as well use that directly. Every compiler will directly replace that with the value in the resulting binary.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be simplified and the `#define` removed to give:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

constexpr auto foo = sizeof(int);
int main() {
    int size;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
        size = foo;
        std::cout<<size<<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you look in the [disassembly](https://godbolt.org/z/4-6oZk) you might be able to see the compiler has hard coded `4` into your executable. Even without `constexpr`, `sizeof` is evaluated at compile time and not at runtime.